# How can I ensure css hover state is active when an element is revealed below the cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a div containing links with a hover property is changed from display:none to display:block, if the mouse pointer is over the links, the hover state is not triggered until the pointer is moved.
Is there a way in javascript to either trigger the hover state or force it to be evaluated when the div is revealed.

To explain the context, I am attempting to implement an early Macintosh dropdown list interface style that involves revealing the list options on top of the drop down list when the list box is clicked on.

When I click on the dropdown div, the dropdown-content is displayed but the top item is not highlighted until you move the mouse.

```js
function openMenu(mybutton) {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var els1 = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
    for(var i = 0; i < els1.length; i++) { // Step through all dropdown elements
        if (els1[i] === mybutton) {
            els[i].classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropdownContainer {
    border: 1px black solid;
    position:relative;
  width:150px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left:-1px;
  width:150px;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float:none;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover, .dropdown-content a:focus {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdownContainer">
    <div onclick='openMenu(this);' class="dropdown">
        All Categories
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">All Categories</a>
        <a href="#">Boards</a>
        <a href="#">Cables</a>
        <a href="#">Memory</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was able to make the first line initially highlight by changing the focus to the first link when the dropdown-content is opened but the problem was then that the the first link stayed highlighted when you moved the mouse over the other links.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using a StackSnippet so that others can reproduce